# My Image not responsive

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to implement a responsive image logo, but it is not responsive always. Image width and height are the same size. Please give me a solution.

```
<div class="navbar-header">
   <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
     <img src="~/img/flying_logo.png" class="img-responsive">
   </a>
</div>
```

CSS.

```
.navbar-brand {
  position: absolute; 
  display: block;
  width: 260px;
  height: 65px; 
  left: 10px; 
  top: 10px;
}
```

Comment: Can you create a http://plnkr.co/ to demonstrate the problem?

Comment: It's a website you can use to test and share html/js/css code snippets. Ideal for helping us to reproduce your problem without any effort from our side. Your question as it is posted now is very tedious to answer, because it takes us a lot of time to make a setup to reproduce your problem, if we even manage to reproduce it.

Answer (score -1):

This works for me:

```
img-responsive {
   max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

Or add your CSS please.

Comment: You shouldn't need custom css for this. This answer defeats the purpose of bootstrap. And actually, this css already applies for img-responsive.

Comment: Thanks for the help,Im try to this your answer, but its not work, :(

Comment: @popovitsj Thats why there is an "Or add your CSS please" If it would already apply it would actually work. But I agree it should not be needed.

Comment: I agree he should provide a reproducable example, but the information we do have is that he uses bootstrap. I guess it's possible that this answer would've helped, but it would mean that he forgot to include the bootstrap css.

Comment: can you add the css of that part as well: `class="img-responsive"`

Answer (score -1):

Just add css for image. Here is code for this.

```
<style>
 .navbar-header img{
   width:100%;
   height:auto;
 }
</style>`
```

After adding this css your image would be responsive for all screens.

Comment: You shouldn't need custom css for this. This answer defeats the purpose of bootstrap.

Comment: Thanks for the help,Im try to this your answer, but its not work, :(

Answer (score -1):

We can use this css for image tag like

```
img{ width:100%; height:auto; }
```

In bootstrap css this tag already available. If not then add.
It will not effect your bootstrap purpose. It works for all images in your site.

Answer (score -1):

Does it help changing your div code to:

```
<div class="navbar-header">
  <a class="navbar-brand img-responsive" href="#">
    <img src="~/img/flying_logo.png">
  </a>
</div>
```